Profile of Steam market seller
I am interested in if there is a chance to get profile of steam market seller as they made some changes and user cant even see in app/web who listed an item. Is there any way to get info of seller using api, etc?
I was using recently activity api where I was able to get name and picture of seller/buyes but they made changes and cant even see seller picture on website.
This is sample of information what I had:
"price": "$171.53",
"time": 1696363521,
"avatar_buyer": "https://avatars.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb.jpg",
"avatar_medium_buyer": "https://avatars.cloudflare.steamstatic.com/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg",
"persona_buyer": "AXYSB",
}
